# Bitly API causing unexpected illegal token

Tags: php, javascript, api, url-shortener

I'm using the Bit.ly API to generate a shorturl of my domain, and then I need to pass it as a javascript variable.
Unfortunately When the short url is generated, it causes an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"
Here is my source code

```
<?php
function get_bitly_short_url($url,$login,$appkey,$format='txt')
{ $connectURL = 'http://api.j.mp/v3/shorten?login='.$login.'&apiKey='.$appkey.'&uri='.urlencode($url).'&format='.$format; return curl_get_result($connectURL);}
function curl_get_result($url) {
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 5;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $data;
}
$short_url = get_bitly_short_url('http://mydomain.com','BitLyUserName','ApiKey');
?>
<script>
var site = "<?php echo $short_url ?>";
var text = "Something else"
</script>
```

Please take a look and help me, I really need it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to trim() the return data. I tested it out and curl was pushing in a newline character after the url, so the js was being output like:

```
var site = "http://j.mp/bMSmZV
";
```

Update the return from your function to be

```
return trim($data);
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: do you know why you need to use trim? or why the there is a line break after the link? Where in the php code is it putting a line break?